# jQuery nicEdit with jQuery form plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-forms-plugin, nicedit

Im using jQuery nicEdit with jQuery form plugin. But nicEdit doesn't seems to pass the data when using with jQuery form plugin. Here is my code

jQuery From Code

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#From').on('submit', function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#submitButton').attr('disabled', ''); // disable upload button
         $(this).ajaxSubmit({
        target: '#output',
        success:  afterSuccess //call function after success
        });
    });
});

function afterSuccess()
{
    //$('#From').resetForm();  // reset form
    $('#submitButton').removeAttr('disabled'); //enable submit button
    //$('#div-loadding').html('');
}
```

Form Code

```
<form action="submit.php" id="From" method="post" >

<textarea name="about" id="mydata" rows="5"></textarea>

<button type="submit" id="submitButton">Submit</button>

</form>
```

nicEditor code

```
bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
new nicEditor().panelInstance('mydata');
});
```

Can anyone give me a hint or tell me how to make this work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: there is no error nicEdit just doesn't pass the data

Answer (score 0):

Before you can send the data you must store the nicEditor data,
so that the text is written in the textarea by nicEditor

```
 var NicEditor = nicEditors.findNicEditor('mydata');
 var inst = NicEditor.instanceById('mydata');
 inst.saveContent();
```